# Subscribe Button ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, axios

I want users to be able to subscribe to my website for any changes. I don't have any backend code and cannot place backend code on my host.

What is the best way for me to make this button work? I already have the button styled, and set up with axios, I just need to find where to put the document/database so I can get it from the frontend.

I currently use formspree.io for the contact form to work.

I am a beginner at this, please help me!

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Typist from "react-typist";
import { Button, makeStyles, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { SubscriptionsRounded } from "@material-ui/icons";
import axios from "axios";
import Configs from "../editable-stuff/configurations.json";
import "../App";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export default function ComingSoonPage() {
  const icons = Configs.icons;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();

  // const [backgroundType, setBackgroundType] = useState(Configs.backgroundType);
  const [hoverstatus, setHoverstatus] = useState([
    "socialicon",
    "socialicon",
    "socialicon",
    "socialicon",
    "socialicon"
  ]);

  const toggleHover = data => {
    const newhoverStatus = [...hoverstatus];
    if (data.event === "enter") {
      newhoverStatus[data.icon.id] = "socialiconhover";
      return setHoverstatus(newhoverStatus);
    } else if (data.event === "leave") {
      newhoverStatus[data.icon.id] = "socialicon";
      return setHoverstatus(newhoverStatus);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const subscribe = document.getElementById("subscribe").value;
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/api/form",
      data: {
        subscribe: subscribe,
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
    history.replace('/submit')
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="comingsoon"
        className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-transparent bgstyle text-light min-vh-100 d-flex align-content-center align-items-center flex-wrap m-0"
      >
        <div className="container container-fluid text-center ">
          <h1 className="display-1">Under Construction...</h1>
          <Typist className="lead" cursor={{ hideWhenDone: true }}>
            <span className="lead">Welcome to my site! We are currently working on this site every minute of an hour.</span>
            <p>Enter your email below and we will notify you when it's ready.</p>
            Check out and follow our social media sites.
          </Typist>
          <div className="p-6" style={{ paddingTop: "40px", paddingBottom: "40px" }}>
            {icons.map(icon => (
              <a
                key={icon.id}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                href={icon.url}
                aria-label={`My ${icon.image.split("-")[1]}`}
              >
                <i
                  className={`fab ${icon.image}  fa-3x ${hoverstatus[icon.id]}`}
                  onMouseOver={() => toggleHover({ icon, event: "enter" })}
                  onMouseOut={() => toggleHover({ icon, event: "leave" })}
                />
              </a>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div>
            <form autoCorrect="off" onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} id="subscribe-form"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "white", flexDirection: "column", padding: "15px", borderRadius: "10px", maxWidth: "650px", display: "inline-block", width: "100%", }}
            >
              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="form-group col-md-8">
                  <TextField required label="Email Address" type="email" id="subscribe" margin="normal" variant="outlined" placeholder="Email Address" style={{ height: "56px", paddingTop: 0, width: "100%", }} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col-md-2" style={{ paddingTop: "13px", }}>
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" className={classes.button} endIcon={<SubscriptionsRounded />}> Subscribe!</Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How is this related to the C++ language?

Comment: When Bjarne Stroustrup added HTML and JavaScript in C++?

Comment: What is your actual question? You need to enable subscriber functionality in your website with out Backend code! It’s something confused